# Firemonkey TControl subclass cannot draw on component

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to try to create a firemonkey visual component and I have seen online that `TControl` gives the basic needs. This is what I have done so far:

```
  TMyTest = class(TControl)
  strict private
    //code...
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    //code...
  end;
```

I have looked at the source code of a FMX component called `PlotGrid` and I have copied what it does. My class descends from TControl (like PlotGrid) and it overrides Paint (like PlotGrid). Look at the code:

```
constructor TMyTest.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  SetAcceptsControls(False);
end;

destructor TMyTest.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyTest.Paint;
var
  i: integer;
  a, b: TPointF;
begin
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
  Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 2;

  a.X := 0; a.Y := Height/2;
  b.X := Width;  b.Y := Height/2;
  Canvas.DrawLine(a, b, 1);
end;
```

Given this code, I expect to have something like this (I have edited with paint the image, it's not the real one)

[image]

The problem is that I get this

[image]

The component is fine because I see all the methods and properties and they work. The component is functional BUT I cannot see it in the designer! If I run the FMX application I cannot see the colors:

[image]

Any idea?

---

I have set the `Opacity := 1;` at the beginning of the `Paint` event but still nothing.

Comment: What is your control's `(Absolute)Opacity` set to?

Comment: How can I check it? I haven't set the opacity anywhere. I have tried Opacity := 1; in the constructor but still nothing

Comment: Are you setting the `Parent` property? Usually it is set when you instantiate the control. As a quick test, add `Parent := AOwner;` in the constructor. Don't leave it like that, though. Owner and parent should not be hardcoded to be the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your control is painting on shared canvas. By the time it reaches your control's `Paint` method value of `Canvas.Stroke.Kind` is `TBrushKind.None` so if you don't assign some other value to it, it will not actually paint anything.

You have to add

```
Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
```

But, that will only paint horizontal line (you forgot to create points and make `DrawLine` call for vertical one) and it will not fill the background with white color.

The simplest way to do so is with

```
Canvas.ClearRect(ClipRect, TAlphaColorRec.White);
```

In general common canvas values can (and will) be changed by other controls. Better way to deal with those is to mimic code from `TShape` providing your own `TFill` and `TStroke` fields and assigning those to canvas before painting. That way you can be sure that you will not miss setting some particular Stroke or Fill value that can be changed outside your control.

Comment: "Default value of Canvas.Stroke.Kind is TBrushKind.None ..."  I'd call that a stroke of genius.  Not.  +1, btw

Comment: @MartynA Actually, it originally starts with Solid, but it is changed to None soon enough... I rephrased the answer to be more accurate.