# Firemonkey component save design time size

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In regard to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017928/firemonkey-tcontrol-subclass-cannot-draw-on-component) question I have been able to create an FMX component that is a white rectangle with a black border that can be drawn inside with the cursor of the mouse (like with MS Paint).

[image]

When I compile and run the program I get this:

[image]

Why?

If I set the `Align` property for example it works (Client aligns this to client). If I align the component to `Center` it is on the center but the size is smaller (like in the picture).

It looks like it doesn't "save" the width and the height that I set on the Object Inspector. My component has this relevant code:

```
type
  Test = class(TControl)
  strict private
    FLineFill: TStrokeBrush;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Align;
property Anchors;
property ClipChildren;
property ClipParent;
property Cursor;
property Enabled;
property Locked;
property Height;
property HitTest;
property Opacity;
property Margins;
property Position;
property Visible;
property Width;
property OnClick;
property OnDblClick;
property OnMouseDown;
property OnMouseMove;
property OnMouseUp;
property OnMouseWheel;
property OnMouseEnter;
property OnMouseLeave;
property OnPainting;
property OnPaint;
property OnResize;
property OnResized;
end;
```

And here's the implementation:

```
constructor Test.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FLineFill := TStrokeBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, $FF222222);
  //more...
end;

destructor Test.Destroy;
begin
  FLineFill.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure Test.Paint;
var
begin
  Canvas.Stroke.Assign(FLineFill);
  Canvas.ClearRect(ClipRect, TAlphaColorRec.White);

  Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  //more code...
end;
```

I have given a look at the source code of `TPlotGrid` which is a simple component and it does what I'm doing basically. Do I have to setup something more in the Paint event?

Comment: You say your control published all properties, but you didn't included them all in your question. It is impossible to say what is missing.

Comment: I have included all the properties

Comment: You seem to be missing `published property Size;` which is required in FMX controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `Size` property because it is the one that takes care of the dimension of the component. It returns [`TControlSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Types.TControlSize) which does exactly what you need. From the doc:

> A TControlSize object is used for managing the size of the component.
>   This can be specified through the Size, Width, Height, and
>   PlatformDefault attributes.

Just add this code in the published part:

```
property Size;
```

---

If you look at its implementation you'll find

```
property Width: Single read GetWidth write SetWidth stored StoreWidthHeight;
property Height: Single read GetHeight write SetHeight stored StoreWidthHeight;
```