# How to use FireMonkey TCanvas.DrawXXX methods?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I try to create a form with a custom visualisation, but I can't get the simplest drawing methods of TCanvas to work. In the following example, I can see only the filled rectangle, but no line and no arc:

```
procedure TEditorPanel.FormPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
var
  center, radius: TPointF;
  rect: TRectF;
begin
  with Canvas do
  begin
    Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.White;
    FillRect(RectF(0, 0, Width, Height), 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);

    center := PointF(200, 200);
    radius := PointF(40, 40);

    Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
    Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Blue;
    DrawLine(center, radius, 1);
    DrawArc(center, radius, 0, 90, 1);

    rect := RectF(10, 10, 100, 100);
    FillRect(rect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 100);
  end;
end;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at this q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017928/firemonkey-tcontrol-subclass-cannot-draw-on-component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Delphi 10.1 or above You should set `Stroke.Kind` to `TBrushKind.Solid` to get lines appear, default value in `None` :

```
var
  center, radius: TPointF;
  rect: TRectF;
begin
  with Canvas do
  begin
    Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.White;
    FillRect(RectF(0, 0, Width, Height), 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);

    center := PointF(200, 200);
    radius := PointF(40, 40);

    Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Stroke.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
    Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Blue;
    DrawLine(center, radius, 1);
    DrawArc(center, radius, 0, 90, 1);

    rect := RectF(10, 10, 100, 100);
    FillRect(rect, 0, 0, AllCorners, 100);
  end;
```